# Button in Iframe sometimes not clickable on Safari iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, button, iframe, safari

*I'm rendering a `button inside an iframe` which is shown on a different page/domain. Everything is working perfectly fine, until you try it out in a `Safari browser using an iOS phone`:*

There's this inconsistency which prevents any touches to the button no matter how many times you touch. Once you press anything else on the page(a dropdown outside of the iframe e.g.), the button inside the iframe suddenly starts working again.

You can also do a long-touch on the button, and it will work.

Trying this in any other environment than Safari/iOS and everything works as expected.

I've already tried adding a `touch-action: auto;` to `html, body` to no avail.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.